# Prevent java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

When executing an `HttpUriRequest` using the `AndroidHttpClient`, it will throw an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null` when the url is faulty.

In my application, the user can input his own url. When for example `http://195.168.0.q` is entered, the `IllegalArgument` is thrown, and the app crashes.

How can I prevent this (preferably, without catching exceptions)?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Does there even exist a regex which covers all possible correct url's?

Comment: What kind of urls you except?

Comment: Everything `HttpClient` accepts.

Comment: There is already a class that handles parsing of URLs and throws a very specific exception if it is not formed correctly (```MalformedURLException```). I don't think re-inventing that is a good idea. I don't think this is against coding standards, I think it is exactly why this exception class was created.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the exception with a 'try-catch(-finally)' block.

```
try {
   // your code
} catch(IllegalArgumentException) {
   // Faulty url
}
```

Comment: There must be a better way, as this goes against coding standards.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the user has supplied a valid URL before trying to use it as one:

```
URL url;
try {
    url = new URL("http://195.168.0.q");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // tell user the URL they entered is invalid
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, exactly this code does not trigger the `catch` clause.